# Cannot print numpy arrays with logging module

Tags: python, numpy, logging, stdout

This snippet doesn't print anything:

```py
import logging
import numpy as np

logging.info(np.eye(4))

# this doesn't work either
logging.info('matrix', np.eye(4))
```

But it works fine with native `print`:

```py
import logging

print(np.eye(4))
```

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with your logging level.

If I try `logging.warning(np.eye(4))`, I get an output in my console.

Try the following code:

```py
import logging
import numpy as np

# Fix logging level issue
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

logging.info(np.eye(4))
```

Output:

```
INFO:root:[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Comment: Yep, as amrit mentioned, default logging level is warning.